# Setup custom object in three

Tags: three.js

I've upgraded to the latest version and noticed that some things have changed.

The renderer doesn't seem to support indexed geometries with more than ~65k indices and the `immidiateRenderCallback` doesn't work anymore.

So how can I add a custom object to the scene?

In previous versions I inherited from `THREE.ImmediateRenderObject` and put everything in the `rendercallback` function.

Answer (score 1):

if you have more than 65k vertices and something is wrong i would suspect that the index is in a

```
Uint16Array
```

make sure you have your index in a

```
Uint32Array
```

with a Uint16Array  every integer there is represented by 16 bits -> so possible values range from 0 to (2^16 -1)=65535 therefore the index is unable to reference vertices higher than that, with 32bit integers you can go up to 4294967296 and that should suffice

Comment: Yea but that works only with the GL_OES_element_index_uint extension and doesn't really answer my question about howto render custom objects with the latest version...

Comment: you will not be able to use indexed geometry with many vertices without OES_element_index_uint, as for the latter part of your question: ImmediateRenderObject works as you can see in the [marchingCubes example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_marchingcubes), unless you improve your question with maybe some code and what exactly is wrong it is unlikely someone will guess what is wrong